Why is each block getting under utilized in ethereum?
The current block gas limit in ethereum is 30 million units but far from getting completely filled they are way underutilized.
Is it because the gas price sent by transaction not attractive enough for validators or is the volume of the transactions low ?
Example of one such block 19868242 -
https://etherscan.io/block/19868242


A bit of both!
The underutilization of the block gas limit in Ethereum can be attributed to the mechanics introduced by EIP-1559, which is discussed extensively in this paper. Here's how it works:

The block gas limit is set at twice the target block size of 15 million gas.
If a block exceeds the target size, the base fee increases in the next block. Conversely, the base fee decreases if a block is under the target size.

This adjustment mechanism of the base fee influences users' decisions to send transactions. If a transaction's fee is below the base fee of a block, it will not be included in that block.
You can see this in action with the example you provided. The next block, block/19868243, has a higher Base Fee Per Gas. The first block that implemented EIP-1559 is block/12965000, and you can observe that the preceding blocks had a gas limit of about 15 million gas, reflecting the current target.
This system ensures that the block size stays around the target, dynamically adjusting the base fee to manage network demand.
